# cropping an image which is zoomed 'Android'

Tags: android, crop, zooming

I am unable to crop the image which is zoomed I am using the below code for zooming an image. Could anyone help me please?

This is the code.

```
public void selectRandomImage()
{
  Cursor c = getContentResolver().query( Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null,  
                                                     null, null );
  if ( c != null ) {
     int count = c.getCount();
     int position = (int)( Math.random() * count );
     if ( c.moveToPosition( position ) ) {
        long id = c.getLong( c.getColumnIndex( Images.Media._ID ) );
        int orientation = c.getInt( c.getColumnIndex( Images.Media.ORIENTATION ) );

        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse( Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI + "/" + id );
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
           bitmap = ImageLoader.loadFromUri( this, imageUri.toString(), 1024, 1024 );
           mImageView.setImageBitmapReset( bitmap, orientation, true );
        }
        catch ( IOException e ) {
           Toast.makeText( this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
     }
     c.close();
     c = null;
     return;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

try out https://github.com/biokys/cropimage may help u.

All The Best

Answer (score 0):

**try this ::**

```
if (itemx.equalsIgnoreCase("capture")) {
            try
            {
            str_Height_of_crop = i1.getStringExtra("height");
            str_Width_of_crop = i1.getStringExtra("width");
            /*int_Height_crop = Integer.parseInt(str_Height_of_crop);
            int_Width_crop = Integer.parseInt(str_Width_of_crop);*/
            int_Height_crop=190;
            int_Width_crop=170;

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tmp_avatar_"
                    + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));
            intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    mImageCaptureUri);


                intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);

            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

rivate void doCrop() {
        final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setType("image/*");

        List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
                intent, 0);

        int size = list.size();

        if (size == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return;
        } else {
            intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

            /*
             * intent.putExtra("outputX", 200); intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
             */

            intent.putExtra("outputX", int_Height_crop);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", int_Width_crop);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            if (size == 1) {
                Intent i = new Intent(intent);
                ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

                i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
                        res.activityInfo.name));

                startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
            } else {
                for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                    final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                    co.title = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(
                            res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(
                            res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.appIntent = new Intent(intent);

                    co.appIntent
                            .setComponent(new ComponentName(
                                    res.activityInfo.packageName,
                                    res.activityInfo.name));

                    cropOptions.add(co);
                }

                CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(
                        getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
                builder.setAdapter(adapter,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                                startActivityForResult(
                                        cropOptions.get(item).appIntent,
                                        CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                            }
                        });

                builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                        if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
                            getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null,
                                    null);
                            mImageCaptureUri = null;
                        }
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                alert.show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank u so much for your response but as am new to android can u plz let me know where to place the related 'code' plzzzzzz.....

Comment: useing this you can capture image througe system camera crop at your selected size and zoom in zoom out at crop time